# Debian Jessie environnment is broken

Tags: debian, apt, xfce, startx

I have a Debian 8.10 Jessie installed on my laptop and since this morning, my environnment behaviour is completely broken : ALT+TAB doesn't work, ALT+F4 doesn't work, I can't move, close or adjust the size of my application (So I just can't close my Firefox window), right clicking on my firefox don't work, I can't see my top bar with my apps and system options.

I tried (from [this](https://superuser.com/questions/371365/recovering-a-broken-gnome-desktop-in-debian-wheezy)) with no success with `startx` not working:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade #see if the package is held back
sudo apt-get purge gnome-session
sudo apt-get install gnome-session
startx
```

I also tried sudo `apt-get dist-upgrade` and `apt-get install gnome-accessibility-themes` and rebooting multiple times but nothing works.
I found `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager` but I have an error of package not found despite having `non-free` indicated in my /etc/apt/sources.list

I'm out of solutions here :(

.xinitrc :

```
#!/bin/sh# /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
## global xinitrc file, used by all X sessions started by xinit (startx)
# invoke global X session script.
/etc/X11/Xsession
```

.xseesion-errors (I remove a lot of files errors output cause it would have made a very long message ):

```
 Xsession: X session started for charles at samedi 10 février 2018, 17:21:17 (UTC+0100)
localuser:charles being added to access control list
openConnection: connect: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
cannot connect to brltty at :0
/usr/bin/x-session-manager: X server already running on display :0
xfce4-session-Message: ssh-agent is already running; starting gpg-agent without ssh support
xfce4-panel: No window manager registered on screen 0. To start the panel without this check, run with --disable-wm-check.
xfsettingsd: No window manager registered on screen 0.

(xfsettingsd:1773): xfsettingsd-WARNING **: Failed to get the _NET_NUMBER_OF_DESKTOPS property.

(xfce4-session:1761): Wnck-CRITICAL **: wnck_workspace_activate: assertion 'WNCK_IS_WORKSPACE (space)' failed

(zeitgeist-datahub:1966): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: invalid (NULL) pointer instance

(zeitgeist-datahub:1966): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_signal_connect_data: assertion 'G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE (instance)' failed

** (terminator:1774): WARNING **: Binding '<Shift><Control><Alt>a' failed!
Unable to bind hide_window key, another instance/window has it.
nm-applet-Message: No keyring secrets found for ABOX/802-11-wireless-security; asking user.

** (terminator:1775): WARNING **: Binding '<Shift><Control><Alt>a' failed!
Unable to bind hide_window key, another instance/window has it.

--------- A lot of error messages -----------

(/opt/firefox/firefox:3600): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion 'object->ref_count > 0' failed

** (terminator:3706): WARNING **: Binding '<Shift><Control><Alt>a' failed!
Unable to bind hide_window key, another instance/window has it.
```

Comment: There looks like no compizconfig-settings-manager in Jessie. Look at https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=compizconfig-settings-manager

Comment: Sounds las if the desktop environment is simply not running.  Please share your `.xinitrc` or `.xsession` file. (and also any error messages or warnings)

Comment: Added it @Kusalananda

Comment: @CharlesDuporge Do you also have a `.xsession` script?

Answer (score 1):

These error messages makes me believe that the XFCE window manager (usually `xfwm4`) was not properly started:

```
xfce4-panel: No window manager registered on screen 0. To start the panel without this check, run with --disable-wm-check.
xfsettingsd: No window manager registered on screen 0.
```

The window manager is the utility that puts decorations on windows and allows you to interact with them (moving them around etc.).

Usually, the XFCE desktop environment should be started from either `~/.xsession` or `~/.xinitrc` using the command `startxfce4`.

For whatever reason, I have the command

```
exec ck-launch-session startxfce4
```

in my own `.xinitrc`.  The `ck-launch-session` is a utility "to start a ConsoleKit session from a shell script", and `exec` replaces the current process with that utility. If you don't use ConsoleKit, then simply remove `ck-launch-session` from that line (I believe I needed to include that to be able to shut down and to reboot from the XFCE menus).

---

I'm not on Debian (or Linux at all), so I can't say that this would definitely be the correct solution to your issue.